# Network Computer Enumeration broken by having SMBv1 turned off

Tags: powershell, networking, enumeration, smb

I've used this code with SMBv1 enabled to list all the computers on my Peer-to-Peer network.

```
(([adsi]"WinNT://$((Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)").Children.path)
```

However, with SMBv1 turned off, the new default in Windows since 1809 it errors out.

I've been googling for months and can't come up with an alternative.  Yes, I know I can turn SMBv1 back on but I'd rather not if at all possible.

Ideas?

Comment: The Windows protocol requirements are protocol requirements in the Core OS. YOu should not expect to be able to supplant or subvert them, otherwise, why would they ever exist. That code is Powershell v2 stuff which really shoudl be fully disabled in your environment as per Microsoft's onwe anouncements. I, know, I know, nany enterprises still have legacy stuff, but you are saying you are on Win10, so, outside of the protocol thing, why are you not using the default built-in cmdlets for this, as well as the newer CIM cmdlets or PowerShell remoting? [a fellow almost retired geek, soooon. ;-}]

Comment: No legacy stuff, this is just my home lan. Which cmdlets would those be?